# iOS Project with SQLCipher and SQLite Dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, adobe, sqlcipher

How can an iOS project be configured so that it can use the [SQLCipher pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SQLCipher) and also install 3rd party pods (like the [Adobe Mobile SDKs](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ACPMobileServices)) which [use `SQLite3`](https://github.com/adobe/aepsdk-core-ios/blob/4.2.3/AEPServices/Sources/dataqueue/SQLiteWrapper.swift#L14)?

SQLCipher has a disclaimer that usage with other pods that depend on `SQLite3` is not supported, but that it should be possible.

[image: SqlCipher Disclaimer]

The guide to do this configuration consists of [configuring the linking order in Xcode](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688). Attempts at doing this have been unsuccessful:

[image: Redefinition of sqlite3_file error message]

A reproduction of the issue and attempted fix is available here: https://github.com/Chuckv01/adobe-sqlcipher-issue-reproduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this `Redefinition of 'sqlite3_file'` error by adding three Preprocessor Macros to the app Target in Xcode:

- `_SQLITE3_H_=1`
- `_FTS5_H=1`
- `_SQLITE3RTREE_H_=1`

Do this for the `Debug` and `Release` environments. Ensure previous macros are preserved and not deleted.

[image: Configure Preprocessor Macros]

Diff of changes:

[image: Diff of changes]